# Retrofit SimpleXMLConverter NumberFormatException on empty attribute

Tags: android, string, square, simple-framework, retrofit

I am using Retrofit and SimpleXMLConverter to get and deserialize an XML file. I am converting an attribute to type long. It would work fine if the attribute wasn´t sometimes "", aka empty.

I tried using

```
@Attribute(empty="-1")
```

for the cases this attribute should be empty, so it should return "-1" but it does not do so. Is the usage of this empty attribute correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It would work fine if the attribute wasn´t sometimes "", aka empty.

This is not correct here: The attributes value - seen as string - is not *empty* in the meaning of missing or "nothing", it's an **empty string**.

Here's an example:

**XML:**

```
<root value=""></root>
```

**Java class:**

```
@Root(name = "root")
public class Example
{
    @Attribute(name = "value", empty = "-1", required = false)
    private long value;


    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Example{" + "value=" + value + '}';
    }
}
```

This throws - and that's reasonable - a `NumberFormatException`. If you replace the type of `value` with `String` you wont catch an exception, value is set as an *empty string* (`""`). On the other hand, keeping string type but removing the attribute in XML will set `"-1"` as value (that's why `required = false` is used). Now the Serializer can't find any value and therefore sets the default one.

You *could* handle this in your class internally, like let the corresponding getter-method return `-1` in case of an empty string:

```
public long getValue()
{
    if( value == null || value.isEmpty() == true )
    {
        return -1;
    }

    return Long.valueOf(value);
}
```

*(Don't forget to change your code according this - in my example you have to change `toString()`-method)*

But there's a *better solution*: Simple allows you to implement *custom [Transformer](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/transform/Transform.html)* for any types (don't mix with *`Converter`*!). With these you can implement *`type -> String` (write)* and *`String -> type`* (read) as you need.

Based on my example above, here's an implementation:

```
public class LongTransformer implements Transform<Long>
{
    // Default value which is set if no / empty input is available
    private final long defaultValue;


    public LongTransformer(long defaultValue)
    {
        this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
    }

    public LongTransformer()
    {
        this(-1); // Just in case you always have -1 as default
    }



    @Override
    public Long read(String value) throws Exception
    {
        // If there's no or an empty String the default value is returned
        if( value == null || value.isEmpty() == true )
        {
            return defaultValue; // 
        }

        return Long.valueOf(value); // Return the value
    }


    @Override
    public String write(Long value) throws Exception
    {
        /*
         * Nothing special here. In case you you need a empty string if
         * value = -1, you can do it here.
         */
        return value.toString();
    }
}
```

And finally a example how to use. The key parts are between the two lines:

```
final String xml = "<root value=\"\">\n"
                 + "</root>";

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
final LongTransformer numberTransformer = new LongTransformer(-1);

RegistryMatcher m = new RegistryMatcher();
m.bind(long.class, numberTransformer);

Serializer ser = new Persister(m);
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------

Example root = ser.read(Example.class, xml);
System.out.println(root);
```

**Output:**

```
Example{value=-1}
```

Comment: What if it was <root value="">test</root>
Hou would you get the "test" string?

Comment: You can use the [`@Text`](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/); see [here](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#text) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

@vandus, here is what  I did so far:
I created an adapter in the Main onCreate class, the Model that I pass in as a List is the root node of the XML file:http://www.w3schools.com//xml/simple.xml

```
      RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint("http://www.w3schools.com")
                .setConverter(new SimpleXMLConverter())
                .build();

            GitHubService foodService = restAdapter.create(GitHubService.class);
            List<BreakfastMenu> repos = foodService.getFile();
            repos.toString();



public interface GitHubService
  {
    @GET("/xml/simple.xml")
    List<BreakfastMenu> getFile();
  }
```

Comment: Could you please create a new, separate, question for your problem? The original question is not related to your problem. I'll answer you there. Just add a comment here about where I can find it.

Comment: Hi. The question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25380280/how-to-use-retrofit-and-simlpexml-together-in-parsing-and-downloading-an-xml-fil