# How to use Retrofit and SimpleXML together in downloading and parsing an XML file from a site?

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp, simple-framework, okio

I just started working with Retrofit. I am working on a project that uses SimpleXML. Can somebody provide me an example in which one fetches an XML from a site e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml" and reads it out?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You will create an interface as a new class in your project:

```
public interface ApiService {
    @GET("/xml/simple.xml")
    YourObject getUser();
}
```

Then in your activity you will call the following:

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                    .setEndpoint("http://www.w3schools.com")
                    .setConverter(new SimpleXmlConverter())
                    .build();

ApiService apiService = restAdapter.create(ApiService.class);
YourObject object = apiService.getXML();
```

To get your libraries correctly, in your build.gradle file you need to do the following:

```
configurations {
    compile.exclude group: 'stax'
    compile.exclude group: 'xpp3'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.1'
    compile 'com.mobprofs:retrofit-simplexmlconverter:1.1'
    compile 'org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
}
```

Then you need to specify YourObject and add annotations to it according to the structure of the xml file

```
@Root(name = "breakfast_menu")
public class BreakFastMenu {
    @ElementList(inline = true)
    List<Food> foodList;
}

@Root(name="food")
public class Food {
    @Element(name = "name")
    String name;

    @Element(name = "price")
    String price;

    @Element(name = "description")
    String description;

    @Element(name = "calories")
    String calories;
}
```

Comment: In this case is my Object the first Node of the Elements Tree, e.g.

Comment: Yes, I am going to provide you with an example of this structure

Comment: Aham awesome. I did the structure based on the xml example. It starts with this Model:

Comment: I know that this is a late reply, but I'm trying to understand what does "inLine = true" do?

Comment: In case you're looking for a more detailed example: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-how-to-integrate-xml-converter

Comment: hi, can you help me to do the same with Retrofit 2 , instead of using "RestAdapter" (but using Retrofit  - > . Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()  
    .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
    .client(new OkHttpClient())
    .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
    .build();)

Comment: @vandus What is getXML()?!

Comment: what about Kotlin?

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

@Root(name = "breakfast_menu")
public class BrakfastMenu
  {
    @ElementList(inline = true)
    protected List<Food> food;

    public List<Food> getConfigurations()
      {
        if (food == null)
          {
            food = new ArrayList<Food>();
          }
        return this.food;
      }

    public void setConfigurations(List<Food> configuration)
      {
        this.food = configuration;
      }

  }
```

Comment: Yep. I have updated my answer with the structure for you. You can also make it simpler, but it is up to you, what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it with **Retrofit 2**.

First you need an interface like (headers annotations are optional) :

```
public interface ApiService
{

    @GET("xml/simple.xml")
    @Headers({"Accept: application/xml",
            "User-Agent: Retrofit-Sample-App"})
    Call<BreakfastMenu> getBreakfastMenu();

}
```

The annotated POJOs for XML are the same as in the other answers.

Then you need to make a request to the server :

```
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://www.w3schools.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    ApiService apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
    Call<BreakfastMenu> call = apiService.getBreakfastMenu();
    Response<BreakfastMenu> response = call.execute();
    // response.code() == 200
    BreakfastMenu breakfastMenu = response.body();
```

The needed libraries are :

- retrofit 2.3.0
- okhttp 3.8.0
- converter-simplexml 2.3.0
- simple-xml 2.7.1
- Java 7

Source available [on my GitHub](https://github.com/ghusta/retrofit2-simplexml-test/)