# Android Retrofit xml with Callback

Tags: android, retrofit

I've been following this article on how to get retrofit to work with xml...
which works.

[How to use Retrofit and SimpleXML together in downloading and parsing an XML file from a site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25380280/how-to-use-retrofit-and-simplexml-together-in-downloading-and-parsing-an-xml-fil)

But It needs to work with a callback. And I just cant get it work.

Has any one else done one?

```
public class LocksXmlDisplay {

@Root(name = "breakfast_menu")
public class BreakFastMenu
{
    @ElementList(inline = true)
    List<Food> foodList;
}

@Root(name="food")
public class Food
{
    @Element(name = "name")
    String name;

    @Element(name = "price")
    String price;

    @Element(name = "description")
    String description;

    @Element(name = "calories")
    String calories;
}

public BreakFastMenu breakFastMenu;
```

}

```
public interface GetKnocksInter {
@GET("/simple.xml")
//LocksXmlDisplay getxml();
void fetchxml(Callback<List<LocksXmlDisplay.Food>> mycallback);
```

}

```
            getKnocksInter.fetchxml(new Callback<List<LocksXmlDisplay.Food>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(List<LocksXmlDisplay.Food> foods, Response response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: What version of retrofit are you using? It's been updated to v2.0 recently and there has been some changes

Comment: Then it should work. Can you give more details about what doesn't work? Maybe put a log on the failure callback and post the error you get

Comment: So Ive just updated it to show locksXMLdisplay...

and the error i get is
java.lang.ClassCastException: libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class

Comment: Im not sure what my callback should be returning..

Comment: Hmmm, I have no Idea about that exception but maybe it has to do with the class you are trying to parse being inside another class?

Comment: @aidanmack could you throw in the XML that causes that exception? Your exception strongly suggests there's a problem with deserialization.