# How to parse Simple XML format using retrofit?

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, retrofit

I have the following response format for XML

```
<idxml>
<Status>Error</Status>
<Msisdn/>
<OperatorCode/>
<OrderId/>
<Details>invalid date</Details>
<Signature/>
</idxml>
```

It would be helpful if you can create a class file for this XML response using retrofit. Thanks is advance.

Comment: refer this https://www.mytrendin.com/parsing-xml-data-using-retrofit2-api/

Comment: take a look here at the answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25380280/how-to-use-retrofit-and-simplexml-together-in-downloading-and-parsing-an-xml-fil

Comment: @Akshay I was using the same but the XML format is different and I am confused creating the class for my response

Comment: your class will be like: 
`
@Root(name = "idxml)
public class ParentAttr{
 @Element
 private String Status;

 @Element
 private String Msisdn;

 @Element
 private String OperatorCode;

 @Element
 private String Details;

 @Element
 private String Signature;
}`