# How to make response class for a specific list (in xml )

Tags: java, android, xml, retrofit2, simple-xml-converter

Newbie to Android and developing an app where using XML parsing with the retrofit.
I have completed all the process and done the task except one.
I don't know how to create the POJO class for the "hours_of_operations" tag in below XML.
A sample code would be a great help.

```
    <dealers>
<dealer>
<name>Minnesota Tile & Stone</name>
<address>
...... </address>
<phone>12345678</phone>
<url>www.xyz.com</url>
<showroom_display_level>ooopppss</showroom_display_level>
<distance>11.76</distance>
<open>false</open>
<hours_of_operations>
<hours_of_operation>
<days>M,W,F</days>
<hours>10:00 - 5:00</hours>
</hours_of_operation>
<hours_of_operation>
<days>T,Th</days>
<hours>10:00 - 8:00</hours>
</hours_of_operation>
<hours_of_operation>
<days>Sat</days>
<hours>10:00 - 4:00</hours>
</hours_of_operation>
</hours_of_operations>
<google_static_map_url>
.......    </google_static_map_url>
<google_map_url>
.......</google_map_url>
</dealer>
```

I have done with all attributes, just not sure about "hours_of_operations" and data inside that. Here is my Dealer class

```
@Root(name = "dealer")
public class Dealer {

@Element(name = "name")
private String name;

@Element(name = "address")
private Address adress;

@Element(name = "phone")
private long phone;

@Element(name = "url")
private String url;

@Element(name = "showroom_display_level", required = false)
private String showroom_display_level;

@Element(name = "distance")
private String distance;

@Element(name = "open", required = false)
private String open;

@Element(name = "hours_of_operations")
private HoursOfOperation hours_of_operations;

@Element(name = "google_static_map_url")
private String google_static_map_url;

@Element(name = "google_map_url")
private String google_map_url;
--getters--n -setters--
```

hoursofoperation class

```
@Root(name = "hours_of_operation", strict = false)
```

public class HoursOfOperation {

```
@Element(name = "days", required = false)
private String days;

@Element(name = "hours", required = false)
private String hours;

getters--setters

Here is my response class


  @Root(name = "dealers", strict = false)
public class ApiResponse {

    @ElementList(inline = true, required = false)
    public List<Dealer> dealerList;

}
```

I am done with this XML, just not sure about the "hours_of_operations"
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please share your json format

Comment: Dont have Json mam :).. just using retrofit and parsing, but not able to parse mentioned tags. @farhana

Comment: How are you getting data, through API?

Comment: Should i need to post my response class? @farhana

Comment: yes exactly, you need to show the response,  Your POJO class will depend on server response .

Comment: @farhana please see the edited questions

Comment: Okay, I see you xml class,  you declare @Element(name = "address") like this but whereas address is the root of other address1,address2 etc

Comment: didnt get it. Please post a sample code

Comment: see this link it will help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25380280/how-to-use-retrofit-and-simplexml-together-in-downloading-and-parsing-an-xml-fil

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Retrofit and SimpleXML together in downloading and parsing an XML file from a site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25380280/how-to-use-retrofit-and-simplexml-together-in-downloading-and-parsing-an-xml-fil)

Comment: @farhana I am done with this parsing, But i am not able to make pojo for that part i have mentioned. I am still at the same point. Thanks