# how to use xml parsing in android using retrofit

Tags: android, xml-parsing, retrofit2

Am new to android i want to parse the xml file using retrofit, i have gone through the links which are posted in stackoverflow
 [How to use Retrofit and SimpleXML together in downloading and parsing an XML file from a site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25380280/how-to-use-retrofit-and-simplexml-together-in-downloading-and-parsing-an-xml-fil)
But in my scenario i have to add headers,how can i achieve this using Retrofit.

Below is the xml parser [image: XmlParser]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sample web service without headers:

```
public interface ApiService {
    @GET("/webservice/xml")
    Call<YourClass> getXml();
}
```

This is how we add static and dynamic headers:

```
public interface ApiService {
    @Headers({"Accept: application/json"})
    @GET("/webservice/xml")
    Call<YourClass> getXml(@Header("Authorization") String authorization);
}
```

Using ApiService:

```
new Retrofit.Builder()
.baseUrl("server ip")
.addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
.build().create(ApiService.class).getXml("This is a value that will be sent as authorization header");
```

In order to use this code you should add these lines to your gradle file:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.1.0') {
    exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
    exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
    exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax'
}
```

Here is a good tutorial https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-add-custom-request-header

Comment: can you please post the sample code by using headers,

Comment: can you please look into this as i am facing nullpointerexception while fetching response https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52945188/how-to-parse-xml-response-using-retrofit-2-0

Answer (score 0):

Example interface with header as a static value:

```
public interface ApiService {

    @Headers("user-key: 9900a9720d31dfd5fdb4352700c")
    @GET("api/v2.1/search/webxml")
    Call<String> getRestaurantsBySearch(@Query("q"), String query);

}
```

Example interface with header as a parameter:

```
public interface ApiService {

    @GET("api/v2.1/search/webxml")
    Call<String> getRestaurantsBySearch(@Query("q"), String query, @Header("user-key") String userkey);

}
```

Comment: can you please look into this as i am facing nullpointerexception while fetching response https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52945188/how-to-parse-xml-response-using-retrofit-2-0