# how to parse XML response using retrofit 2.0?

Tags: android, xml-parsing, retrofit

Hi am new to android programming i have gone through some links for how to parse the XML response using retrofit and i tried for below XML as shown.

Is there any necessary changes i have to do in POJO class. but am getting NullPointer Exception in Logcat. when am trying to read the response.

Can any one please look into it and help me out.

this is my XML response for Login API.

[[image: xml_response[1]]

Here is my MainActivity code. can any one suggest where am getting wrong.

```
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/xml"), strRequestBody);

    Call<LoginResponseEnvelope> call = RetrofitGenerator.getProductInterfaceApi().Login(requestBody);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponseEnvelope>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponseEnvelope> call, Response<LoginResponseEnvelope> response) {
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            if (response != null) {
                try {
                    Log.d("LoginResponse", "success response :" + response.body());
                    LoginResponseEnvelope loginResponseEnvelope = response.body();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

               /* if (loginResponseEnvelope != null) {
                    Log.d("LoginResponse", "success loginResponseEnvelope :" + loginResponseEnvelope.toString());

                    String status = loginResponseEnvelope.getBody().getLoginResponseData().getLoginResult().getLoginInfo().toString();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SuccessActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }*/
            }

            /*if (loginResponseEnvelope!=null){

            }*/
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponseEnvelope> call, Throwable t) {
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Log.d("LoginResponse", "failure response :" + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

this is my retrofit POJO class for XML response.

```
public class LoginResponseEnvelope {

@Element(name = "Body", required = false)
private LoginResponseBody body;

public LoginResponseBody getBody() {
    return body;
}

public void setBody(LoginResponseBody body) {
    this.body = body;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "LoginResponseEnvelope{" +
            "body=" + body +
            '}';
}

@Root(name = "Body", strict = false)
public class LoginResponseBody {

    @Element(name = "LoginResponse", required = false)
    private LoginResponseData loginResponseData;

    public LoginResponseData getLoginResponseData() {
        return loginResponseData;
    }

    public void setLoginResponseData(LoginResponseData loginResponseData) {
        this.loginResponseData = loginResponseData;
    }

    @Root(name = "LoginResponse", strict = false)
    @Namespace(reference = "http://tempuri.org/")
    public class LoginResponseData {

        @Element(name = "LoginResult", required = false)
        private LoginResult loginResult;

        public LoginResult getLoginResult() {
            return loginResult;
        }

        public void setLoginResult(LoginResult loginResult) {
            this.loginResult = loginResult;
        }

        @Root(name = "LoginResult", strict = false)
        public class LoginResult {

            @Element(name = "Result", required = false)
            private LoginInfo loginInfo;

            public LoginInfo getLoginInfo() {
                return loginInfo;
            }

            public void setLoginInfo(LoginInfo loginInfo) {
                this.loginInfo = loginInfo;
            }

            @Root(name = "Result", strict = false)
            @Namespace(reference = "")
            public class LoginInfo {

                @Element(name = "Success", required = false)
                private Success success;

                public Success getSuccess() {
                    return success;
                }

                public void setSuccess(Success success) {
                    this.success = success;
                }

                @Root(name = "Success", strict = false)
                public class Success {

                    @ElementList(name = "CompanyDetails", inline = true)
                    private List<Company> companyDetails;

                    public List<Company> getCompanyDetails() {
                        return companyDetails;
                    }

                    public void setCompanyDetails(List<Company> companyDetails) {
                        this.companyDetails = companyDetails;
                    }

                    @Root(name = "CompanyDetails", strict = false)
                    public class Company {

                        @Element(name = "Id", required = false)
                        private String id;

                        @Element(name = "Name", required = false)
                        private String Name;

                        public String getId() {
                            return id;
                        }

                        public void setId(String id) {
                            this.id = id;
                        }

                        public String getName() {
                            return Name;
                        }

                        public void setName(String name) {
                            Name = name;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

For example you have an XML string:

```
<Response>
    <Field1>string</Field1>
    <Field2>string</Field2>
    <Field3>string</Field3>
    <Field4>string</Field4>
</Response>
```

First, add to your `gradle` file:

```
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.6.1"
```

Next, add to your `retrofit` builder:

```
.addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
```

Note: `SimpleXmlConverterFactory` is deprecated now, but I've not found a better solution

And your model class:

```
@Root(name = "Response")
data class Response @JvmOverloads constructor(
@field:Element(name = "Field1")
var bucket: String = "",
@field:Element(name = "Field2")
var key: String = "",
@field:Element(name = "Field3")
var etag: String = "",
@field:Element(name = "Field4")
var location: String = ""
)
```

Note: properties need to be predefined

Your `ApiService` file will be the same as you are parsing json

Comment: `Note: SimpleXmlConverterFactory is deprecated now, but I've not found a better solution` do you mind telling the better solution ?

Comment: Hi. I wrote "I have not found a better solution". So after that I had no tasks with XML and can't tell you anything about better solution

Comment: oh, sorry i mis -read it.

Comment: No problem man. If you find the better solution, please write here.

Comment: TikXML
https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2733