# Not able to parse XML response in Retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, xml-parsing, retrofit2

I am not able to parse the XML response in retrofit as consume the SOAP webservice by POJO classes but at the end its showing NullPointerException as the body of response is null.

I tried everything and gone through every links but still facing same issue.

Can anyone please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: show your code..

Comment: @Gayathri please look into this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52945188/how-to-parse-xml-response-using-retrofit-2-0